# How to create Celery Windows Service?

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, celery

I'm trying to create a Windows Service to launch Celery. I have come across an article that does it using [Task Scheduler](http://www.calazan.com/windows-tip-run-applications-in-the-background-using-task-scheduler/). However it seems to launch numerous celery instances and keeps eating up memory till the machine dies. Is there any way to launch it as a Windows service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the answer from another website. Celeryd (daemon service for Celery) runs as a paster application, searching for 'Paster Windows Service' lead me [here](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/How+to+run+Pylons+as+a+Windows+service). It describes how to run a Pylons application as a Windows Service. Being new to paster framework and hosting python web services, it didn't cross my mind to check it at first. But that solution works for Celery with a slight change here and there in the script.

I've modified the script to make it easier for modifying Celery settings. The essential changes are:

1. Create an INI file with the settings for Celery service (shown below)
2. Create a python script to create a Windows service.

INI file settings (celeryd.ini):

```
[celery:service]
service_name = CeleryService
service_display_name = Celery Service
service_description = WSCGI Windows Celery Service
service_logfile = celeryd.log
```

Python script to create Windows Service (CeleryService.py):

```
"""
The most basic (working) Windows service possible.
Requires Mark Hammond's pywin32 package.  
Most of the code was taken from a  CherryPy 2.2 example of how to set up a service
"""
import pkg_resources
import win32serviceutil
from paste.script.serve import ServeCommand as Server
import os, sys
import ConfigParser

import win32service
import win32event

SCRIPT_DIR          = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
INI_FILE            = 'celeryd.ini'
SERV_SECTION        = 'celery:service'
SERV_NAME           = 'service_name'
SERV_DISPLAY_NAME   = 'service_display_name'
SERV_DESC           = 'service_description'
SERV_LOG_FILE       = 'service_logfile'
SERV_APPLICATION    = 'celeryd'
SERV_LOG_FILE_VAR   = 'CELERYD_LOG_FILE'

# Default Values
SERV_NAME_DEFAULT           = 'CeleryService'
SERV_DISPLAY_NAME_DEFAULT   = 'Celery Service'
SERV_DESC_DEFAULT           = 'WSCGI Windows Celery Service'
SERV_LOG_FILE_DEFAULT       = r'D:\logs\celery.log'

class DefaultSettings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if SCRIPT_DIR:
            os.chdir(SCRIPT_DIR)
        # find the ini file
        self.ini = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR,INI_FILE)
        # create a config parser opject and populate it with the ini file
        c = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
        c.read(self.ini)
        self.c = c

    def getDefaults(self):
        '''
        Check for and get the default settings
        '''
        if (
            (not self.c.has_section(SERV_SECTION)) or
            (not self.c.has_option(SERV_SECTION, SERV_NAME)) or
            (not self.c.has_option(SERV_SECTION, SERV_DISPLAY_NAME)) or
            (not self.c.has_option(SERV_SECTION, SERV_DESC)) or
            (not self.c.has_option(SERV_SECTION, SERV_LOG_FILE))
            ):
            print 'setting defaults'
            self.setDefaults()
        service_name = self.c.get(SERV_SECTION, SERV_NAME)
        service_display_name = self.c.get(SERV_SECTION, SERV_DISPLAY_NAME)
        service_description = self.c.get(SERV_SECTION, SERV_DESC)
        iniFile = self.ini
        service_logfile = self.c.get(SERV_SECTION, SERV_LOG_FILE)
        return service_name, service_display_name, service_description, iniFile, service_logfile

    def setDefaults(self):
        '''
        set and add the default setting to the ini file
        '''
        if not self.c.has_section(SERV_SECTION):
            self.c.add_section(SERV_SECTION)
        self.c.set(SERV_SECTION, SERV_NAME, SERV_NAME_DEFAULT)
        self.c.set(SERV_SECTION, SERV_DISPLAY_NAME, SERV_DISPLAY_NAME_DEFAULT)
        self.c.set(SERV_SECTION, SERV_DESC, SERV_DESC_DEFAULT)
        self.c.set(SERV_SECTION, SERV_LOG_FILE, SERV_LOG_FILE_DEFAULT)
        cfg = file(self.ini, 'wr')
        self.c.write(cfg)
        cfg.close()
        print '''
you must set the celery:service section service_name, service_display_name,
and service_description options to define the service 
in the %s file
''' % self.ini
        sys.exit()


class CeleryService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    """NT Service."""

    d = DefaultSettings()
    service_name, service_display_name, service_description, iniFile, logFile = d.getDefaults()

    _svc_name_ = service_name
    _svc_display_name_ = service_display_name
    _svc_description_ = service_description

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        # create an event that SvcDoRun can wait on and SvcStop
        # can set.
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        os.chdir(SCRIPT_DIR)
        s = Server(SERV_APPLICATION)
        os.environ[SERV_LOG_FILE_VAR] = self.logFile
        s.run([self.iniFile])
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.stop_event, win32event.INFINITE)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        #win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(CeleryService)
```

To install the service run `python CeleryService.py install` and then `python CeleryService.py start` to start the service. **NOTE**: These commands should be run in command-line with administrator rights.

If the service needs to be removed, run `python CeleryService.py remove`.

I was trying to host Celery as part of enhancing my RhodeCode installation. This solution seems to work. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: How do you set a broker in such a case, Redis for example

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer does not apply for running celery with a Django application. But it inspired me to come up with a solution for running celery as a Windows service with Django. Note that the following is for Django projects only. It may work with other applications with some modifications.

The following discussion assumes Python >= 3.6 and RabbitMQ are already installed, and `rabbitmq-server` is running on `localhost`.

Create a file celery_service.py (or whatever you like) inside your Django project's top level folder, same level as manage.py, with the following content:

```
'''Usage : python celery_service.py install (start / stop / remove)
Run celery as a Windows service
'''
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import subprocess
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shlex
import logging
import time

# The directory for celery.log and celery_service.log
# Default: the directory of this script
INSTDIR = Path(__file__).parent
# The path of python Scripts
# Usually it is in path_to/venv/Scripts.
# If it is already in system PATH, then it can be set as ''
PYTHONSCRIPTPATH = INSTDIR / 'venvcelery/Scripts'
# The directory name of django project
# Note: it is the directory at the same level of manage.py
# not the parent directory
PROJECTDIR = 'proj'

logging.basicConfig(
    filename = INSTDIR / 'celery_service.log',
    level = logging.DEBUG, 
    format = '[%(asctime)-15s: %(levelname)-7.7s] %(message)s'
)

class CeleryService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    _svc_name_ = "Celery"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Celery Distributed Task Queue Service"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)           

    def SvcStop(self):
        logging.info('Stopping {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))        
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        sys.exit()           

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        logging.info('Starting {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))
        os.chdir(INSTDIR) # so that proj worker can be found
        logging.info('cwd: ' + os.getcwd())
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        command = '"{celery_path}" -A {proj_dir} worker -f "{log_path}" -l info -P eventlet'.format(
            celery_path=PYTHONSCRIPTPATH / 'celery.exe',
            proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
            log_path=INSTDIR / 'celery.log')
        logging.info('command: ' + command)
        args = shlex.split(command)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
        logging.info('pid: {pid}'.format(pid=proc.pid))
        self.timeout = 3000
        while True:
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # stop signal encountered
                # terminate process 'proc'
                PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
                handle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, proc.pid)
                win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
                win32api.CloseHandle(handle)                
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(CeleryService)
```

Before the script can be run, you need to

1. Optionally create a python virtual environment e.g. 'venvcelery'.
2. Install the following requirements:

   django>=2.0.0
   sqlalchemy>=1.0.14
   celery>=4.3.0,<5.0
   pywin32>=227
   eventlet>=0.25
3. Fix pywin32 `pywintypes36.dll` location. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200068)
4. Correctly set PYTHONSCRIPTPATH and PROJECTDIR in celery_service.py

PYTHONSCRIPTPATH is usually the "Scripts" folder under your python's installation path or current virtual environment

PROJECTDIR is the directory name of the Django project.

It is the directory at the same level of manage.py, not the parent directory.

Now you can install / start / stop / remove the service with:

```
python celery_service.py install
python celery_service.py start
python celery_service.py stop
python celery_service.py remove
```

I created a demo Django project with celery running as a Windows service:

https://github.com/azalea/django_celery_windows_service

In case you are interested in a running example.

---

Note: this is an updated version assuming Python >= 3.6, Django 2.2 and Celery 4.

An older version with Python 2.7, Django 1.6 and Celery 3 can be viewed in edit history.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but even in the latest documentation, it seems like `celeryd` is still being used, although it does also mention using Django to 'daemonize' Celery: http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html#init-script-celeryd

Comment: @ViteFalcon Thank you for pointing it out. I have edited my wording. Feel free to edit and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

@azalea 's answer helped me a lot, but one thing I like to highlight here is, the service (celery_service.py) needs to be installed with your user/password, otherwise, when you run `subprocess.Popen(args) in SvcDoRun()` function, nothing will happen as there will be a permission issue. To set the user/password, you can choose one of two methods:

1. Using command line:

   ```
   python33 .\celeryService1.py --username .\USERNAME --password PASSWORD
   ```
2. Go to Computer Management(local) > Services and Applications > Services, find your server (in @azalea's example, it is "Celery Distributed Task Queue Service"), and right click to open Properties page, input "This account" in Log On tab

Answer (score 0):

A good project here but didn't succeed to use it :
[Link to the GitHub of the django-windows-tools](https://github.com/antoinemartin/django-windows-tools).
It gave me a timeout at the last command line. Doesn't have enough time to search why.

The package allow settings FastCGI, Celery and Static files of a Django project on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Azalea as this led me to the path in being able to create 2 windows services with Celery 4 on Windows.

One to be able to start/stop multiple workers T
Second to be able to start/stop the beat service and tidy up the pid using Celery 4.

Only caveat in this that I do not have a solution for is you can not restart the workers as you need to ensure the spawned processes for multiple are stopped before starting back up.

Workers.py:

```
'''Usage : python celery_service.py install (start / stop / remove)
Run celery as a Windows service
'''
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import shlex
import logging
import time

# The directory for celery_worker.log and celery_worker_service.log
# Default: the directory of this script
INSTDIR = 'X:\Application\Project'
LOGDIR = 'X:\Application\LogFiles'
# The path of python Scripts
# Usually it is in PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR/Scripts. e.g.
# r'C:\Python27\Scripts'
# If it is already in system PATH, then it can be set as ''
PYTHONSCRIPTPATH = 'C:\Python36\Scripts'
# The directory name of django project
# Note: it is the directory at the same level of manage.py
# not the parent directory
PROJECTDIR = 'Project'

logging.basicConfig(
    filename = os.path.join(LOGDIR, 'celery_worker_service.log'),
    level = logging.DEBUG, 
    format = '[%(asctime)-15s: %(levelname)-7.7s] %(message)s'
)

class CeleryService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    _svc_name_ = "CeleryWorkers"
    _svc_display_name_ = "CeleryWorkers"

    def __init__(self, args): 
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        logging.info('Stopping {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))        
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        logging.info('Stopped1 {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))   
        logging.info('Stopped3 {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_)) 
        command = '"{celery_path}" -A {proj_dir} --workdir=X:/Application/Project control shutdown --timeout=10'.format(
        celery_path=os.path.join(PYTHONSCRIPTPATH, 'celery.exe'),
        proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
        log_path=os.path.join(LOGDIR,'celery_worker.log'))
        logging.info('command: ' + command)
        args = shlex.split(command)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
        logging.info('Stopped celery shutdown  ...') 
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        logging.info('Stopped2 {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))  
        sys.exit()           

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        logging.info('Starting {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))
        os.chdir(INSTDIR) # so that proj worker can be found
        logging.info('cwd: ' + os.getcwd())
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        command = '"{celery_path}" -A {proj_dir} -c 8 worker --workdir=X:/Application/Project --pidfile=celeryservice.pid  -f "{log_path}" -l info'.format(
            celery_path=os.path.join(PYTHONSCRIPTPATH, 'celery.exe'),
            proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
            log_path=os.path.join(LOGDIR,'celery_worker.log'))
        logging.info('command: ' + command)
        args = shlex.split(command)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
        logging.info('pid: {pid}'.format(pid=proc.pid))
        self.timeout = 3000
        while True:
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # stop signal encountered
                # terminate process 'proc'
                PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
                handle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, proc.pid)
                win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
                win32api.CloseHandle(handle)                
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(CeleryService)
```

Beatservice.py:

```
'''Usage : python celery_service.py install (start / stop / remove)
Run celery as a Windows service
'''
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import shlex
import logging
import time
import signal

# The directory for celery_beat.log and celery_beat_service.log
# Default: the directory of this script
INSTDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
LOGPATH = 'X:\Application\Logs'
# The path of python Scripts
# Usually it is in PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR/Scripts. e.g.
# r'C:\Python27\Scripts'
# If it is already in system PATH, then it can be set as ''
PYTHONSCRIPTPATH = 'C:\Python36\Scripts'
# The directory name of django project
# Note: it is the directory at the same level of manage.py
# not the parent directory
PROJECTDIR = 'PROJECT'

logging.basicConfig(
    filename = os.path.join(LOGPATH, 'celery_beat_service.log'),
    level = logging.DEBUG, 
    format = '[%(asctime)-15s: %(levelname)-7.7s] %(message)s'
)

class CeleryService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    _svc_name_ = "CeleryBeat"
    _svc_display_name_ = "CeleryBeat"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)           

    def SvcStop(self):
        logging.info('Stopping 1 {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))        
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        pidno = open("X:\Aplication\Project\celerybeat.pid", "r")
        _pid_id_ = pidid=pidno.read()
        pidno.close()
        logging.info(_pid_id_)
        logging.info('taskkill /F /PID {pidid} ..'.format(pidid=_pid_id_))
        cmdcom = 'taskkill /F /PID {pidid}'.format(pidid=_pid_id_)
        logging.info(cmdcom)
        killargs = shlex.split(cmdcom)
        process = subprocess.Popen(killargs)
        output, error = process.communicate()
        logging.info(output)
        logging.info('Stopping 2 {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))
        os.remove("X:\Application\PROJECT\celerybeat.pid")
        logging.info('X:\Application\PROJECT\celerybeat.pid  file removed')
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        sys.exit()

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        logging.info('Starting {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))
        os.chdir(INSTDIR) # so that proj worker can be found
        logging.info('cwd: ' + os.getcwd())
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        command = '"{celery_path}" -A {proj_dir} beat --workdir=X:/Application/Project -f X:/Application/logs/beat.log -l info'.format(
            celery_path=os.path.join(PYTHONSCRIPTPATH, 'celery.exe'),
            proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
            log_path=os.path.join(LOGPATH,'celery_beat.log'))
        logging.info('command: ' + command)
        args = shlex.split(command)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
        logging.info('pid: {pid}'.format(pid=proc.pid))
        self.timeout = 3000
        while True:
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # stop signal encountered
                # terminate process 'proc'
                PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
                handle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, proc.pid)
                win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
                win32api.CloseHandle(handle)                
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(CeleryService)
```