# Starting Celery worker in windows

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to start celery worker in windows 7 with the following command

```
celery worker -A routes.celery --loglevel=info
```

result of the above command is

```
c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\celery': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

is command "celery" is designed only for Unix-like system?
if so then how to start celery worker from python script instead of command line.

Comment: How is your configuration to celery and the structure to project, you could show me please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378932/how-to-create-celery-windows-service this migth help you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't install celery package on your machine. That is why your Python doesn't recognize 'celery' command.