# Starting Application as a service before logon using python

Tags: python, windows, service

I want to start an exe before login and I am trying to achieve this using Python. Below is a sample code that I am trying to use where `SMWinservice` is defined [here](https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2018/08/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/?doing_wp_cron=1561897401.6327629089355468750000).

```py
# imports are there

class MyService(SMWinservice):
    _svc_name_ = 'testService1'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Test Service 1'
    _svc_description_ = 'Test ServiceFramework 1 Description'

    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def main(self):
        subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe')
        # i=0
        # while self.isrunning:
        #     with open('C:\\test1323.txt','a') as file:
        #         file.write(datetime.now().isoformat()+'\n')
        #     i=i+1
        #     time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyService.parse_command_line()
```

The above code works fine when I simply try to write something in a file (after looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200068/python-windows-service-error-starting-service-the-service-did-not-respond-to-t) and solving errors).

But the exe doesn't start up when I try to start the service(manually or by restating the PC) and I don't understand why. What am I missing or what is wrong? How should I approach such a problem. I am new to windows functionality through the eyes of python. I have stuck in this for days and any code or help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I changes the `main` method to the following.

```py
def main()
    self.process = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe')
    while self.isrunning:
        if self.process.pid not in psutil.pids():
            self.isrunning = False

        with open('C:\\logs.txt','a') as file:
            file.write(str(self.process.pid)+'\n')

        time.sleep(5)
    self.process.kill()
```

When I start the process, I can see the process pid being updated in `C:\logs.txt`. The process can also be seen running in Task Manager as notepad++.exe running. But the application is not there in the foreground. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to restriction that services cannot interact with Desktop from Windows Vista times.