# Detecting USB Device Insertion on Windows 10 using python

Tags: python, windows-10, usb

I can't get the following code for [Detecting USB Device Insertion](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/detect-device-insertion.html) to work on my Windows 10 (64 bit) computer with Python 3.7.

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager

import win32gui
import win32gui_struct
struct = win32gui_struct.struct
pywintypes = win32gui_struct.pywintypes
import win32con

GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = "{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}"
DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000
DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004

import ctypes

#
# Cut-down clone of UnpackDEV_BROADCAST from win32gui_struct, to be
# used for monkey-patching said module with correct handling
# of the "name" param of DBT_DEVTYPE_DEVICEINTERFACE
#
def _UnpackDEV_BROADCAST (lparam):
  if lparam == 0: return None
  hdr_format = "iii"
  hdr_size = struct.calcsize (hdr_format)
  hdr_buf = win32gui.PyGetMemory (lparam, hdr_size)
  size, devtype, reserved = struct.unpack ("iii", hdr_buf)
  # Due to x64 alignment issues, we need to use the full format string over
  # the entire buffer.  ie, on x64:
  # calcsize('iiiP') != calcsize('iii')+calcsize('P')
  buf = win32gui.PyGetMemory (lparam, size)

  extra = {}
  if devtype == win32con.DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE:
    fmt = hdr_format + "16s"
    _, _, _, guid_bytes = struct.unpack (fmt, buf[:struct.calcsize(fmt)])
    extra['classguid'] = pywintypes.IID (guid_bytes, True)
    extra['name'] = ctypes.wstring_at (lparam + struct.calcsize(fmt))
  else:
    raise NotImplementedError("unknown device type %d" % (devtype,))
  return win32gui_struct.DEV_BROADCAST_INFO(devtype, **extra)
win32gui_struct.UnpackDEV_BROADCAST = _UnpackDEV_BROADCAST

class DeviceEventService (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

  _svc_name_ = "DevEventHandler"
  _svc_display_name_ = "Device Event Handler"
  _svc_description_ = "Handle device notification events"

  def __init__(self, args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__ (self, args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent (None, 0, 0, None)
    #
    # Specify that we're interested in device interface
    # events for USB devices
    #
    filter = win32gui_struct.PackDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE (
      GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE
    )
    self.hDevNotify = win32gui.RegisterDeviceNotification (
      self.ssh, # copy of the service status handle
      filter,
      win32con.DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE
    )

  #
  # Add to the list of controls already handled by the underlying
  # ServiceFramework class. We're only interested in device events
  #
  def GetAcceptedControls(self):
    rc = win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.GetAcceptedControls (self)
    rc |= win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT
    return rc

  #
  # Handle non-standard service events (including our device broadcasts)
  # by logging to the Application event log
  #
  def SvcOtherEx(self, control, event_type, data):
    if control == win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT:
      info = win32gui_struct.UnpackDEV_BROADCAST(data)
      #
      # This is the key bit here where you'll presumably
      # do something other than log the event. Perhaps pulse
      # a named event or write to a secure pipe etc. etc.
      #
      if event_type == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        servicemanager.LogMsg (
          servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
          0xF000,
          ("Device %s arrived" % info.name, '')
        )
      elif event_type == DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
        servicemanager.LogMsg (
          servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
          0xF000,
          ("Device %s removed" % info.name, '')
        )

  #
  # Standard stuff for stopping and running service; nothing
  # specific to device notifications
  #
  def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus (win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent (self.hWaitStop)

  def SvcDoRun(self):
    win32event.WaitForSingleObject (self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)
    servicemanager.LogMsg (
      servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
      servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
      (self._svc_name_, '')
    )

if __name__=='__main__':
  win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine (DeviceEventService)
```

1. I start the script with the following command: `python main.py start`
2. Then the following error messages appear in the command prompt:

`Starting service DevEventHandler
Error starting service: Access denied`

3. I then ran the script with administrator privileges: `runas /user:administrator "python main.py start"`
4. Another error messages appear in the command prompt:

`Starting service DevEventHandler
Error starting service: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.`

How can the 'The specified service does not exist as an installed service' error be fixed?

Comment: This doesn't like it will solve your issue, but it should be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41200068/11301900.

Comment: @AMC In the meantime I have tried almost all relevant tips and tricks, but starting a Windows service in Python still does not work.

Comment: Someone posted about this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273252/detect-inserted-usb-on-windows/4274450#4274450

Comment: @zer02 I already know this post. See my comment there.

Comment: @nathancy In my case I would like to include all USB devices and not just USB drives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested with Python 3.8.2 x64.

1. Install pywin32 (`pip install pywin32`)
2. Install the current/last version (1.5) of the WMI module from https://github.com/tjguk/wmi (`pip install -e git+https://github.com/tjguk/wmi.git#egg=wmi`)
3. run a script (`test.py` in my case), like:

```py
import wmi

raw_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_USBHub\'"
c = wmi.WMI ()
watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=raw_wql)
while 1:
  usb = watcher ()
  print(usb)
```

4. plug in a USB device. Output looks like:

```
(wmi-py) C:\Users\USER\Source\wmi-py>py test.py

instance of Win32_USBHub
{
        Caption = "USB Composite Device";
        ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
        ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
        CreationClassName = "Win32_USBHub";
        Description = "USB Composite Device";
...
```

Many thanks to the WMI module author, and the Windows nerds' discussion here [Detecting USB drive insertion and removal using windows service and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp)

Comment: The following error messages appear after starting the script:
1: "Traceback (most recent call last):"
2: "File "wmi-usb-detector.py", line 5, in <module>"
3: "watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=raw_wql)"
4: "File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1103, in watch_for"
5: "wmi_class = getattr (self, class_name)"
6: "TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string"

Comment: @Atalanttore you're using WMI module version 1.4.9 - the one that comes with pip. The specific version IS important.

Comment: You're right. It was version 1.4.9. Installing version 1.5.0 from GitHub has fixed this issue. Also thanks for updating your instructions.

Comment: Don't work i get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'"

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the script with *debug* argument and a message saying that service is not installed appeared.
Try first to type

> python main.py install

then

> python main.py start

Comment: "python main.py install" causes the following (error) messages: "Installing service DevEventHandler" and "Error installing service: Access denied (5)"

Comment: Yes, I have changed the command from step 3 (see above). Unfortunately a message appears with the message that "python main.py install" is attempted to start as user "DESKTOP-LL3RM2P\administrator", then the script is terminated.