# Detecting insertion/removal of USB input devices on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, usb

I already have some working Python code to detect the insertion of some USB device types (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60653067/7481773)).

```
import wmi

raw_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_USBHub\'"
c = wmi.WMI()
watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=raw_wql)
while 1:
    usb = watcher()
    print(usb)
```

Unfortunately this script does not detect the insertion of all types of USB devices. This means that the insertion of USB flash drives is detected, but USB input devices are not. The removal of USB devices is not detected at all.

Is there a way to extend the existing script accordingly?

**EDIT: Better WQL query and Python code**

I've improved the WQL query and Python code based on information I got in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f365565c-49d4-4394-aef6-939fa44e5212/wmi-query-for-insertionremoval-of-usb-input-devices?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues).

The following script is intended to output a message when a USB keyboard is plugged in or unplugged.

**Issue:** No message appears when a USB keyboard is plugged in, but both messages ("Keyboard connected" and "Keyboard disconnected") appear when the USB keyboard is unplugged. What's wrong with this code?

```
import wmi

device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

c = wmi.WMI()
connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

while 1:
    connected = connected_watcher()
    disconnected = disconnected_watcher()
    if connected:
        print("Keyboard connected")
    if disconnected:
        print("Keyboard disconnected")
```

Comment: Try to alter your `raw_wql` query. This is one you found here in another question, that might not fit your need. Try to use a more general statement to get more events, then when you detect the event you are looking for narrow it down by a more specific statement.

Comment: @Joe Thanks to the help of another friendly user I was able to build a suitable query. See URL: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f365565c-49d4-4394-aef6-939fa44e5212/wmi-query-for-insertionremoval-of-usb-input-devices?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: Good. If you like please answer your own question by adding the solution. Else please delete the question.

Comment: @Joe Unfortunately, this possible solution as a whole does not yet work as required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to detect what is happening with device changes

[Detecting USB Insertion / Removal Events in Windows using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078909/detecting-usb-insertion-removal-events-in-windows-using-c)

One suggested way is to use WM_DEVICECHANGE message. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078996/2830850

One such example an be found at below

```py
#Modified from: http://wiki.wxpython.org/HookingTheWndProc
##########################################################################
##
##  This is a modification of the original WndProcHookMixin by Kevin Moore,
##  modified to use ctypes only instead of pywin32, so it can be used
##  with no additional dependencies in Python 2.5
##
##########################################################################


import sys
import ctypes
#import GUID
from ctypes import c_long, c_int, wintypes

import wx


GWL_WNDPROC = -4
WM_DESTROY  = 2
DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000005  # device interface class
DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004  # device is gone
DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000  # system detected a new device
WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219

class GUID(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("Data1", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("Data2", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("Data3", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("Data4", ctypes.c_ubyte * 8)]

## It's probably not neccesary to make this distinction, but it never hurts to be safe
if 'unicode' in wx.PlatformInfo:
    SetWindowLong = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW
    CallWindowProc = ctypes.windll.user32.CallWindowProcW
else:
    SetWindowLong = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongA
    CallWindowProc = ctypes.windll.user32.CallWindowProcA

## Create a type that will be used to cast a python callable to a c callback function
## first arg is return type, the rest are the arguments
#WndProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, wintypes.HWND, wintypes.UINT, wintypes.WPARAM, wintypes.LPARAM)
WndProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)

if 'unicode' in wx.PlatformInfo:
    RegisterDeviceNotification = ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterDeviceNotificationW
else:
    RegisterDeviceNotification = ctypes.windll.user32.RegisterDeviceNotificationA
RegisterDeviceNotification.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
RegisterDeviceNotification.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.c_void_p, wintypes.DWORD]

UnregisterDeviceNotification = ctypes.windll.user32.UnregisterDeviceNotification
UnregisterDeviceNotification.restype = wintypes.BOOL
UnregisterDeviceNotification.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE]

class DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dbcc_size", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dbcc_devicetype", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dbcc_reserved", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dbcc_classguid", GUID),
                ("dbcc_name", ctypes.c_wchar * 256)]

class DEV_BROADCAST_HDR(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dbch_size", wintypes.DWORD),
              ("dbch_devicetype", wintypes.DWORD),
              ("dbch_reserved", wintypes.DWORD)]

GUID_DEVCLASS_PORTS = GUID(0x4D36E978, 0xE325, 0x11CE,
        (ctypes.c_ubyte*8)(0xBF, 0xC1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2B, 0xE1, 0x03, 0x18))
GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = GUID(0xA5DCBF10L, 0x6530,0x11D2,
        (ctypes.c_ubyte*8)(0x90, 0x1F, 0x00,0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED))

class WndProcHookMixin:
    """
    This class can be mixed in with any wxWindows window class in order to hook it's WndProc function.
    You supply a set of message handler functions with the function addMsgHandler. When the window receives that
    message, the specified handler function is invoked. If the handler explicitly returns False then the standard
    WindowProc will not be invoked with the message. You can really screw things up this way, so be careful.
    This is not the correct way to deal with standard windows messages in wxPython (i.e. button click, paint, etc)
    use the standard wxWindows method of binding events for that. This is really for capturing custom windows messages
    or windows messages that are outside of the wxWindows world.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.__msgDict = {}
        ## We need to maintain a reference to the WndProcType wrapper
        ## because ctypes doesn't
        self.__localWndProcWrapped = None
        self.rtnHandles = []

    def hookWndProc(self):
        self.__localWndProcWrapped = WndProcType(self.localWndProc)
        self.__oldWndProc = SetWindowLong(self.GetHandle(), GWL_WNDPROC, self.__localWndProcWrapped)

    def unhookWndProc(self):
        SetWindowLong(self.GetHandle(), GWL_WNDPROC, self.__oldWndProc)
        ## Allow the ctypes wrapper to be garbage collected
        self.__localWndProcWrapped = None

    def addMsgHandler(self,messageNumber,handler):
        self.__msgDict[messageNumber] = handler

    def localWndProc(self, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam):
        # call the handler if one exists
        # performance note: "in" is the fastest way to check for a key
        # when the key is unlikely to be found
        # (which is the case here, since most messages will not have handlers).
        # This is called via a ctypes shim for every single windows message
        # so dispatch speed is important
        if msg in self.__msgDict:
            # if the handler returns false, we terminate the message here
            # Note that we don't pass the hwnd or the message along
            # Handlers should be really, really careful about returning false here
            if self.__msgDict[msg](wParam,lParam) == False:
                return

        # Restore the old WndProc on Destroy.
        if msg == WM_DESTROY: self.unhookWndProc()

        return CallWindowProc(self.__oldWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)

    def registerDeviceNotification(self, guid, devicetype=DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE):
        devIF = DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE()
        devIF.dbcc_size = ctypes.sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        devIF.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

        if guid:
            devIF.dbcc_classguid = GUID.GUID(guid)
        return RegisterDeviceNotification(self.GetHandle(), ctypes.byref(devIF), 0)

    def unregisterDeviceNotification(self, handle):
        if UnregisterDeviceNotification(handle) == 0:
            raise Exception("Unable to unregister device notification messages")


# a simple example
if __name__ == "__main__":

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame,WndProcHookMixin):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            WndProcHookMixin.__init__(self)
            wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,"Insert and Remove USE Device and Watch STDOUT",size=(640,480))

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)

            #Change the following guid to the GUID of the device you want notifications for
            #self.devNotifyHandle = self.registerDeviceNotification(guid="{3c5e1462-5695-4e18-876b-f3f3d08aaf18}")
            dbh = DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE()
            dbh.dbcc_size = ctypes.sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)
            dbh.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE
            dbh.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE
            self.devNotifyHandle = RegisterDeviceNotification(self.GetHandle(), ctypes.byref(dbh), 0)
            self.addMsgHandler(WM_DEVICECHANGE, self.onDeviceChange)
            self.hookWndProc()

        def onDeviceChange(self,wParam,lParam):
            print "WM_DEVICECHANGE [WPARAM:%i][LPARAM:%i]"%(wParam,lParam)

            if wParam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                print "Device Arrival"
            elif wParam == DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                print "Device Remvoed"

            if lParam:
                dbh = DEV_BROADCAST_HDR.from_address(lParam)
                if dbh.dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE:
                    dbd = DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.from_address(lParam)
                    #Verify that the USB VID and PID match our assigned VID and PID
                    if 'Vid_10c4&Pid_8382' in dbd.dbcc_name:
                        print "Was Our USB Device"

            return True

        def onClose(self, event):
            self.unregisterDeviceNotification(self.devNotifyHandle)
            event.Skip()

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Above is taken from https://github.com/weiwei22844/UsefullPython/blob/fa8603b92cb0b3f6ce00c876f24138211f47e906/HookUsbMsg.py

Now coming back to your code

```py
import wmi

device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

c = wmi.WMI()
connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

while 1:
    connected = connected_watcher()
    disconnected = disconnected_watcher()
    if connected:
        print("Keyboard connected")
    if disconnected:
        print("Keyboard disconnected")
```

The way you call is `connected_watcher` and `disconnected_watcher` in series, both are blocking call. So when you call it first `connected` becomes true and then the `disconnected_watcher` gets called which blocked until a device is disconnected. That is why when you disconnected, you see  both the messages together.

The way you can fix it is by making sure you time out these queries

```py
while 1:
    try:
        connected = connected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
    except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
      pass
    else:
        if connected:
            print("Keyboard connected")

    try:
        disconnected = disconnected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
    except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
      pass
    else:
        if disconnected:
            print("Keyboard disconnected")
```

Another approach is to use threads. But to make your code thread compatible you need to make it like below

```py
class VolumeRemovalWatcher:
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        self.stop_wanted=False
        self.callback=callback
    def stop(self):
        self.stop_wanted = True
    def watch_for_events(self):
        if not threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread():
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()

        try:
            w = WMI()
            watcher = w.Win32_VolumeChangeEvent.watch_for(EventType=3)
            while not self.stop_wanted:
                try:
                    event = watcher(timeout_ms=1000)
                except x_wmi_timed_out:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(event.DriveName)
                    if self.callback is not None:
                        self.callback(event.DriveName)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return None
        finally:
            if not threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread():
                pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Credits for above code to https://github.com/utytlanyjoe/pyWmiHandler/blob/89b934301990a4a955ec13db21caaf81d9a94f63/wmi_wrapper.py

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation. For now, I will use the code without threading, because I have hardly dealt with threading at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to look at the wmi source, but I believe it is threaded in a way that requires asynchronous code for multiple watchers. See [this part of the documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html#watchers-with-timeouts) for info on multiple watchers without async code.

It might be worth modifying your wql query to watch for both `__InstanceCreationEvent`s and `__InstanceDeletionEvent`s, then sorting out which actually occurred based on the information that the watcher kicks back to you.