# Detecting insertion/removal of USB input devices on Windows 10 running in VirtualBox

Tags: python, windows-10, usb, virtualbox

I once again already have some working Python code to detect the insertion/removal of specific USB device types in Windows 10 (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158399/detecting-insertion-removal-of-usb-input-devices-on-windows-10)).

```
import wmi

device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

c = wmi.WMI()
connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

while 1:
    try:
        connected = connected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
    except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
      pass
    else:
        if connected:
            print("Keyboard connected")

    try:
        disconnected = disconnected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
    except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
      pass
    else:
        if disconnected:
            print("Keyboard disconnected")
```

I wanted to use this code in a Python script that runs on Windows 10 **in VirtualBox** 6.0.22 on Ubuntu 18.04 (x64). VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed.

Unfortunately this script does not work, because it does not display any message when a USB keyboard is inserted or removed. Does the VirtualBox configuration need to be changed for this?

However, the following error appears when exiting the script:
`Process finished with exit code -1`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, instead of `while 1:`, use `While True:`. Then, make sure that your USB drive is configured correctly in VirtualBox (this [link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/mount-usb-drive-virtualbox/) may help). And what I found for `Process finished with exit code -1` is all related to PyCharm, idk if you are using this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your tips. Unfortunately VirtualBox on my Ubuntu system does not show any connected USB devices to choose from (unlike as described in the link).