# Crash after several seconds of execution with multithreading

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

Based on code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856614/detecting-insertion-removal-of-usb-input-devices-on-windows-10-running-in-virtua) and [here](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/) I made my first steps with multithreading in PyQt5. After starting the program, the graphical user interface appears, but after several seconds it crashes with the following error

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

After googling the error message, I am relatively sure that something is wrong with multithreading. Unfortunately I don't know what and how the error can be fixed.

**Code**

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

import wmi

from PyQt5. QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView


class KeyboardDetectorSignals(QObject):
    keyboard_changed = pyqtSignal(str)


class KeyboardDetector(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = KeyboardDetectorSignals()

    def run(self):

        device_connected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"
        device_disconnected_wql = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \'Win32_Keyboard\'"

        c = wmi.WMI()
        connected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_connected_wql)
        disconnected_watcher = c.watch_for(raw_wql=device_disconnected_wql)

        while True:
            try:
                connected = connected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if connected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard connected.")

            try:
                disconnected = disconnected_watcher(timeout_ms=10)
            except wmi.x_wmi_timed_out:
                pass
            else:
                if disconnected:
                    self.signals.keyboard_changed.emit("Keyboard disconnected.")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Keyboard Logger")

        self.log_table = QTableWidget()
        self.log_table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.log_table.setShowGrid(True)
        self.log_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Time", "Event"])
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.log_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.log_table)
        self.show()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        keyboard_detector = KeyboardDetector()
        keyboard_detector.signals.keyboard_changed.connect(self.add_row)
        self.threadpool.start(keyboard_detector)

    def add_row(self, event: str):
        now = datetime.now()
        datetime_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        row_count = self.log_table.rowCount()
        self.log_table.insertRow(row_count)
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 0, QTableWidgetItem(datetime_string))
        self.log_table.setItem(row_count, 1, QTableWidgetItem(event))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Update 1:** Removed `@pyqtSlot()`.

Got the following error when running the script from the CMD:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ata\pycharmprojects\test\src\wmi\wmi.py", line 1340, in connect
    obj = GetObject(moniker)
  File "C:\Users\ata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 72, in GetObject
    return Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\ata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 87, in Moniker
    moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221020, 'Ung³ltige Syntax', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ata\pycharmprojects\test\src\wmi\wmi.py", line 1354, in connect
    handle_com_error()
  File "c:\users\ata\pycharmprojects\test\src\wmi\wmi.py", line 258, in handle_com_error
    raise klass(com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi_uninitialised_thread: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147221020, 'Ung³ltige Syntax', None, None)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in run
    c = wmi.WMI()
  File "c:\users\ata\pycharmprojects\test\src\wmi\wmi.py", line 1357, in connect
    raise x_wmi_uninitialised_thread("WMI returned a syntax error: you're probably running inside a thread without first calling pythoncom.CoInitialize[Ex]")
wmi.x_wmi_uninitialised_thread: <x_wmi: WMI returned a syntax error: you're probably running inside a thread without first calling pythoncom.CoInitialize[Ex] (no underlying exception)>
PS C:\Users\ata\PycharmProjects\Snippets\KeyboardLogger>
```

Comment: Can you run your script from the CMD to get a more descriptive error message? Also remove `pyqtSlot`

Comment: @eyllanesc See Update 1.

Comment: add `import pythoncom` and add `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` before `device_connected_wql = "SELECT ...`

Comment: @eyllanesc Great! Using pythoncom has fixed the issue. I have never heard of the module `pythoncom` before, let alone used it.

Answer (score 1):

`PyQt` is thread-safe to the same extent that `Qt` is thread-safe. The `Qt docs` will tell you which parts of their API are guaranteed to be so, and under what circumstances.

`Cross-thread signals` are `thread-safe.`

A thread-safe way of writing this would be to use a `mutex`

Comment: Thanks. I've never used a `mutex` either.